# Testing Kaldor's Second Law

Tags: regression, productivity, r

According to Kaldor's second law, as manufacturing industry grows, the productivity in manufacturing will increase:

$$p_i=f(g_m)$$

And, from the article of Heather Wells and A.P. Thirlwall  (Testing Kaldor’s Growth Laws across the Countries of Africa) the productivity is defined as the difference between growth of manufacturing sector and employment growth in manufacturing:

$$p=e-m$$

So, as was done in the research, I regress the independent variable of growth to the dependent variable of employment. So that the coefficient $1-\beta_1$ will represent the coefficient for the relationship of Kaldor's second law.

I recollected some information from TURKSTAT about these two variables from 2010 to 2023 (until march). When I introduced these datasets into R in order to get the coefficient of regression values It found that $\beta_1=0.03987 $. But because the values are distributed in a wide range of possibilites, I suspect that would be an appopriate way to evaluate the Kaldor's second law.

[image]

Does this imply that the coefficient for the relationship between growth of manufacturing and manufacturing productivity growth is equal to $1-\beta_1=0.96013$? Because I am new to the concept of regression can anyone explain where do I fall behind and made mistakes?